# Flickering windows and menus - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics

so I'm a new user, just installed Ubuntu on the 14th, so a few days ago. At first it worked fine, but now I have a problem where any time my mouse goes over the taskbar, it disappears, and all of my windows yesterday.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS straight from the website and installed it by erasing Windows 10. My computer has a Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 processor and Intel® Q45/Q43 graphics card, as far as I can find.

The problem just started today, and attempting to update the Intel drivers failed to solve the problem. Googling the issue has done nothing, so I'm sort of at my wit's end, as I was planning to use this computer heavily and I can't even open another program without opening the terminal because the menus flicker out. Unity dash (that is the equivalent of the start menu, right?) won't open and I don't know the program name for Chromium so I'm using Mozilla at the moment.

Any sort of help would be appreciated, thank you.

Edit: My question isn't a duplicate to the one linked because of a few reasons:

1) When my desktop loads, it looks normal. I have the sidebar and everything, it's just when I mouse over the sidebar that it disappears.

2) I can sort of alt-tab; for example, from mozilla I can switch to the Ubuntu Software window (which I managed to open by mousing over the sidebar, waiting for the flicker to end, and clicking it right as it came back up), and back, with a flicker only from Mozilla to the Ubuntu Software window, but not back.

3) My system doesn't crash, but when I tell it to shutdown from the top menu, it just sits there. If I tell it to reboot from the terminal, it works.

Windows key does not work, though.

Comment: I have started trying the fix proposed, but I can barely start it. I have ticked the box for Pre-released updates (xenial-proposed) but from there I'm having some trouble figureing out what it's asking me to do.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Then run the two commands mentioned (i.e. `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri/xenial-proposed` and `sudo reboot`) in Terminal. Then it asks you to add three lines mentioned there to `/etc/apt/preferences.d/proposed-updates` file. To do that run `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/preferences.d/proposed-updates`. Text editor should open the file. Add the suggested three lines (`Package: *  
 Pin: release a=xenial-proposed
    Pin-Priority: 400`) to the file, save the file and exit text editor.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't figure out how to make the file.  I did what you said and this popped up in the terminal.

(gedit:2281): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (gedit:2281): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-enabled not supported

** (gedit:2281): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported

Comment: Ignore those warnings if the file is written and saved successfully.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for helping me with that. I wans't lying when I said I was new to this, so you laying it out step by step for me really helped. The taskbar and Unity Dash do work now, so I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Please don't mention it. I hope you'll get to learn a lot from the community and share your knowledge with newer or less experienced users in future.